# Shell command returning empty on Node.js

Tags: node.js, shell, express

I have the following code Node.js to run shell commands.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.all('/commands', function(req, res) {
    var command = exec('rhythmbox-client --print-playing', function(err, stdout, stderr) {

        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
        res.send({res: stdout});

    });
});
app.listen(3000);
```

The problem is that some commands like "amixer sset Master 40" for example, returns the output of the command correctly, and others like "rhythmbox-client - print-playing" return an empty output.

The strange thing is that when both are running on the terminal, they generate output, but when executed by Node.js, only a few commands generate output.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you check `err` and `stderr` ?

Comment: Yes dystroy, `err` return `null` and `stderr` return empty ("").

Comment: Just checking : does that process end ? Does it return a reasonably sized output (less than 200K) ?

Comment: Sorry, how to check this ?

Comment: When you run it in the terminal, does the process end ? You might want to check in node if you receive something using `require('child_process').spawn('your command', [your args]).stdout.on('data', function(d) { console.log(d) })`.

Comment: By the way, I can not use `spawn` because every time returns the following error: `Error: spawn ENOENT`

Comment: What operating system are you running Node on? Please add an `exit` listener to your child process, and post the returned field `code` from the callback function. (`child.on('exit', function(code, signal) {})`)